# MYSQL - JOIN/SUB-SELECT where not all rows have the required column but some do

Tags: mysql

Hello I'm struggling with how to solve an issue and have attempted sub-selects and joins however can't get the result I need. Below is an over-simplified database schema.

The outcome I'm looking for is to be able to provide the SUM(order_items.quantity) grouped by sessions.start_time.

Where this gets complicated is that not all entires in order_items have a valid session_id. There is one entry that does though and they have the order_id in common.

For example (order_items table assuming session_id = start_date 01-02-2024):

| ID | Order_id | Session_id | qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | NULL | 5 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 | -1 | 2 |

The intended output would be

```
start_date | SUM(qty)

01-02-2024 | 11
```

In essence I need some sort of join/sub select that can provide the SUM(order_items.quantity) grouped by sessions.start_time however can someone use the fact there is one order_items entry with a valid session_id and the rest have the order_items.order_id in common.

I've tried various types of join (right, left etc) to no avail

**Orders**

- ID -int

**Order_Items**

- ID -int
- Order_ID -int
- Session_ID -int
- quantity -int

**Sessions**

- ID -int
- start_time -datetime

Comment: it would be possible to acquire the session id for all orderid = 1 but not for orderid = 2 since this is not joinable in any discernible way to orderid 1 and the session ids are different ie 1. and -1. or are the dots in the sample typos?

Comment: @P.Salmon - the dots are typos apols

Comment: sessionid looks like it should belong in orders not order_items

Comment: @P.Salmon decided not to associate session_id with order as its possible for a customer to create a booking whereby they are booking for different sessions.

For instance a single order with the order_Items that relate to different session times. Think like a single order however the order items are 2 hair appointments each for a different session time

Comment: ??are you now saying that and order_id in order items may have many different sessionids and some may be invalid? if so i fon't see what logic can be applied to acquire the sessionids for the invalid ones

Comment: I gave perhaps a really poor example with the hair appointments. However going back to the example of 2 hair appointments - that would be 4 entries into order_items.

1 entry for the first appointment <- these always have a session_id
1 entry for the booking fee for the first appoint <- these don't have a session id
1 entry for the second appointment
1 entry for the booking fee for the second appoint

make sense - the actual appointments always have a sesssion_id, however the booking fee's dont.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s.start_time, SUM(oi.quantity) AS total_quantity
FROM sessions s
JOIN (
    SELECT COALESCE(oi.Session_ID, oi_common.Session_ID) AS Session_ID, oi.quantity
    FROM order_items oi
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT Order_ID, Session_ID
        FROM order_items
        WHERE Session_ID IS NOT NULL
    ) oi_common ON oi.Order_ID = oi_common.Order_ID
) oi ON s.ID = oi.Session_ID
GROUP BY s.start_time
```

This quert sum the quantities from `order_items` by associating valid `Session_IDs` and then linking them to `sessions` to retrieve the `start_time`.

Answer (score 0):

Try This query.

```
SELECT
s.start_time,
SUM(oi.quantity) AS total_quantity FROM
Sessions s JOIN(
    SELECT
        o.Order_ID,
        MAX(s.Session_ID) AS Session_ID
    FROM
        Order_Items o
    LEFT JOIN
        Sessions s ON o.Session_ID = s.ID
    GROUP BY
        o.Order_ID
) subq ON s.ID = subq.Session_ID JOIN
Order_Items oi ON subq.Order_ID = oi.Order_ID GROUP BY
s.start_time;
```